# A fraction of something

Tags: meaning

Does "a fraction of something" always imply less than one unit? Or could it be 4/3 for example?

Comment: [**fraction**, noun, defn 3:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fraction) *a part as distinct from the whole of anything; **portion or section***

Comment: @FumbleFingers that is not the *only* definition of **fraction**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Incorrect.  4/4 is also a fraction.  As is 1/1.

Comment: Arithmetic: 4/3 is a "fraction" of what? Not a whole but more than the whole? When the numerator is greater than the denominator, it's an "improper" fraction. Do not consider that case.

Comment: @Kris "Improper" in the context of "Improper Fractions" is simply a category, not a value judgement.  Improper Fractions are *still* fractions, just as irrational numbers are *still* numbers (and eminently worthy of consideration).

Comment: @itsbruce Please check usage. **Never** understand "fraction" in general English usage to be anything but a "proper fraction." Note that in math, the term is intentionally and appropriately chosen, not for fancy. HTH. :)

Comment: @Kris The OP specifically asks "does it *always* imply less".  This is "English Language & Usage", not "English Language only when used casually".

Comment: If we accept **4/3** as a "fraction", I see no obvious reason why we shouldn't do the same for, say, **1,000,000/1**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Precisely.  If the context is one where accuracy is expected.  In casual use, that would be pedantry, of course.

Comment: @FF In maths, this is well-defined: The integers are a set of numbers and (isomorphic to) a subset of the rationals.

Comment: @itsbruce Unless the context otherwise requires, a "fraction" is a "proper fraction" by default. Save everyone's breath.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the simple mathematical definition of a fraction is that it is a rational number expressed as the ratio of **a** and **b** where **a** and **b** are both integers.  That they are different integers is *not* part of the definition.  In category theory, labelling one variable **a** and another **b** gives the *option* that they be different, not the requirement.

Comment: While in mathsspeak a fraction is any rational (though even in mathsspeak the default sense is common fraction rather than improper fraction // fraction given in decimal format / percentage), X / Y of would only be used where X is less than Y (or, in very rare teaching introductions, equal to Y).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If the default sense is "common fraction" then you are indeed incorrect.  The opposite of an improper fraction is a proper one, not a common one, and both of those are subsets of the set of common fractions.  4/3 and 1/1 are both common fractions.

Comment: @itsbruce source?

Comment: For proper/improper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Simple.2C_common.2C_or_vulgar_fractions and http://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/DevelopmentalMath/COURSE_TEXT_RESOURCE/U02_L1_T2_text_final.html For a clear general definition of fractions http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fraction  Would either of you care to cite evidence for this "default" claim?  How can it even matter, if only common usage is relevant, as both of you have said?  Either the technical meaning is irrelevant or you should accept it and stop cherry-picking arbitrary portions of it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a fraction *of something* is understood to be **a fraction of a whole**. This directly reflects the etymology (*fractus* — 'broken'). Thus it strongly implies that it is less than a unit.

This is actually not only the etymology of the expression, but also the genesis of fractions. Looking at the Wikipedia entry [Fractions (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29), it begins

> A fraction (from Latin: fractus, "broken") represents a part of a whole or, more generally, any number of equal parts.

and [below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#History),

> The earliest fractions were reciprocals of integers: ancient symbols representing one part of two, one part of three, one part of four, and so on.

One may find it convenient to be able to perform computations using, e.g., *thirds* as units of counting. But these are *fractions* per se, mathematical expressions, to be distinguished from *fractions of something*.

Even if one decides to count in slices of pizza, for aught I care, one has to start with slicing some wholes of pizza.

Answer (score 0):

"He works only a fraction of the time."  This would be understood to mean a *small* fraction.

But we could think of other cases.

> "This is the new prison."
>   "What fraction is in use?"
>   "It is now at 120 percent of its designed capacity."

Comment: But the language has changed from fraction of prison used to number of inmates compared to intended capacity.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, a fraction is simply the [quotient of two integer numbers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fraction) (see the second definition on that link).  **4/3** is a fraction.  So is **1/1**.  *In a mathematical context*, the answer is then **"No"**.  In almost any other context, though, most people would assume you meant "less than one/100%/all" if you referred to "a fraction of something, so the answer would be **Yes**.

So my answer is "It depends on the context but in most contexts 'Yes'".

Comment: Back to wrong. The expression '3/4 etc of' is not used for, for instance, '8/7 of'. In maths or elsewhere.  And this is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @anemone Amended as you requested for clarity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm having difficulty parsing what you wrote but it seems to be an argument with something I haven't actually said.

Comment: You're discussing accepted usages of the word 'fraction' rather than accepted usages of the term 'a fraction of ...'. In a related example, 'of' corresponds to the binary operation 'times', but only when the first number mentioned is a number between 0 and 1: 3/4 of 20, 3/4 of 1/2; *4 of 5; *20 of 3/4

Comment: OK, now *that's* an argument.  Fine.  But I'm saying that in a technical context, dealing with the kind of pedants I work with every day, you *could not assume* that "a fraction of" implies a ratio less than one.  In the same way that physicists and engineers know that acceleration can be negative and would never assume that somebody would only ever say "deceleration" when a negative acceleration was involved.  So in my answer, I mentioned that special case.  And then said "in any other case, it  *will* (almost certainly) mean less than one".

Comment: But this is ELU, not Maths SS. // But apologies for concentrating on non-technical linguistics at the expense of well-defining mathematical terms.

Comment: As I said to Kris, English is also used by mathematicians (and scientists and software engineers).  And what they class as casual conversation is rather more pedantic and accurate than the norm.  So I included that context, although emphasising its niche.  Next you'll be trying to tell me there's no place for pedantry on ELU (which would require the deletion of a *very* proper fraction of the content).

Comment: The number of Google hits for "four-thirds of" is less than a tenth of a percent of that for "three-quarters of". And few seem to relate to registers outside mathematical / trade names. Specialist registers (eg legalese) are not likely to be of great use to many of the people coming to ELU rather than to dedicated websites.

Comment: Always.  The question is "Does it *always* imply".  I do not choose to take arbitrary Google percentages as an excuse for sloppiness.

Comment: Imply. The question is "Does it always _imply_". The first sense for _imply_ given by [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imply) for _imply_ is _1. to express or indicate by a hint; suggest_. Not the _involve as a necessary consequence_ sense. I'd say ' "a fraction of something" always suggests – no, at the very least strongly suggests – less than one unit to any person who has a reasonable knowledge of English usage.

Comment: The OP has given no context.  You have made an assumption.  I have not.  Given the use of "always" in the question, I will not make that assumption in an answer.

Comment: You are assuming that 'imply' in some way depends on the audience. The connotation of 'part of the whole' is there whether or not the audience is blinkered.

Comment: This has become beyond pointless[continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21596/discussion-between-itsbruce-and-edwin-ashworth).

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic: 4/3 is a "fraction" of what? Not a whole but more than the whole?

When the numerator is greater than the denominator, it's an "improper" fraction. Do not consider that case.

> a fraction of something

is always to be interpreted as "a **proper** fraction of something," i.e., the case when the numerator is less than the denominator.

Comment: Will Mr. Genius please address the audience? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/improper-fractions.html#notwrong

Comment: @itsbruce 1. Please see my comment at OP. 2. Do not confuse between maths and general English usage.

Comment: The OP did not say the phrase would never be used in a technical context.  "Does it *always* imply?".

Comment: Your statement about not considering improper fractions is simply wrong and not relevant.  If general English usage is the only relevant context, then the difference between improper, proper and common fractions is completely irrelevant (because those mathematical terms are not in common use) and unnecessary.  If you *do* insist on using the technical definitions as justification, then their actual meaning *is* pertinent.  Taking "improper function" and choosing the non-technical  meaning of "improper" *is* confusing maths and general English usage.  You're doing that, not me.